# how to do interrupt service routine in pic18

Tags: assembly, pic, pic18

```
#include<p18f452.inc>
TIMER set 0x00
COUNT1 set 0x01
COUNT2 set 0x02
    org 0x00
    goto start
    org 0x08
    goto int_1
    goto int_2
    org 0x18
    retfie

start   movlw 0xFF
    movwf TRISB,A
    clrf TRISD,A
    clrf TRISC,A
    movlw 0x3F
    movwf PORTD,A
    movlw 0x3F
    movwf PORTC,A

set_time BSF RCON,7,A ;INTERUPT
    BSF INTCON,7,A
    BSF INTCON,4,A
    BCF INTCON,1,A
    bsf INTCON3,4,A
    bcf INTCON3,0,A
    movlw D'60'
    movwf TIMER,A
    call TIME_1
    goto set_time


TIME_1  movlw 0x85
          movwf T0CON,A
loopt   movlw 0x3D
    movwf TMR0H,A
    movlw 0x09
    movwf TMR0L,A
    bcf INTCON,2,A
wait    btfss INTCON,2,A
    bra wait
    decfsz TIMER,F,A
    bra loopt
    return

int_1   btfss INTCON,1,A
    goto eint_1
    incf COUNT1,F,A
    btfsc COUNT1,3,A
    goto num_9
    btfsc COUNT1,2,A
    goto num_7654
    btfsc COUNT1,1,A
    goto num3_2
    btfsc COUNT1,0,A
    goto num1
eint_1  retfie

int_2   btfss INTCON3,0,A
    goto eint_2
    incf COUNT2,F,A
    btfsc COUNT2,3,A
    goto num_9_2
    btfsc COUNT2,2,A
    goto num_7654_2
    btfsc COUNT2,1,A
    goto num3_2_2
    btfsc COUNT2,0,A
    goto num1_2
eint_2  retfie


num_9   btfsc COUNT1,0,A
    goto nom9
    goto nom8
num_7654    btfss COUNT1,1,A
    goto nom4_5
    goto nom6_7
num3_2  btfss COUNT1,0,A
    goto nom2
    goto nom3
num1    movlw 0x06
    movwf PORTD,A
    goto eint_1 


nom9    movlw 0x67
    movwf PORTD,A
    goto eint_1
nom8    movlw 0x7F
    movwf PORTD,A
    goto eint_1
nom6_7  btfss COUNT1,0,A
    goto nom6
    goto nom7
nom6    movlw 0x7D
    movwf PORTD,A
    goto eint_1
nom7    movlw 0x07
    movwf PORTD,A
    goto eint_1
nom4_5  btfss COUNT1,0,A
    goto nom4
    goto nom5
nom4    movlw 0x66
    movwf PORTD,A
    goto eint_1
nom5    movlw 0x6D
    movwf PORTD,A
    goto eint_1
nom2    movlw 0x5B
    movwf PORTD,A
    goto eint_1
nom3    movlw 0x4F
    movwf PORTD,A
    goto eint_1


num_9_2 btfsc COUNT2,0,A
    goto nom9_2
    goto nom8_2
num_7654_2  btfss COUNT2,1,A
    goto nom4_5_2
    goto nom6_7_2
num3_2_2    btfss COUNT2,0,A
    goto nom2_2
    goto nom3_2
num1_2  movlw 0x06
    movwf PORTC,A
    goto eint_2 


nom9_2  movlw 0x67
    movwf PORTC,A
    goto eint_2
nom8_2  movlw 0x7F
    movwf PORTC,A
    goto eint_2
nom6_7_2    btfss COUNT2,0,A
    goto nom6_2
    goto nom7_2
nom6_2  movlw 0x7D
    movwf PORTC,A
    goto eint_2
nom7_2  movlw 0x07
    movwf PORTC,A
    goto eint_2
nom4_5_2    btfss COUNT2,0,A
    goto nom4_2
    goto nom5_2
nom4_2  movlw 0x66
    movwf PORTC,A
    goto eint_2
nom5_2  movlw 0x6D
    movwf PORTC,A
    goto eint_2
nom2_2  movlw 0x5B
    movwf PORTC,A
    goto eint_2
nom3_2  movlw 0x4F
    movwf PORTC,A
    goto eint_2
    end
```

actually this coding is for people counter and display in 7 segment. but the problem is when running this program,it's did'nt function and i don't know where is the problem. i think i had do it correctly..

Comment: You have not mentioned on specific problem you are facing ? Are you getting into interrupts ?

Comment: C18 compiler is supported for PIC18, you might want to switch over to C. Its much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Instead absolute code model I realy advice to use relocatable code model.

To write interrupt under PIC18 than just write:

CODE SAMPLE:

```
#include<p18f452.inc>
_Shared        udata_acs        0        ;Shared memory file registers
IntReg1        res              1
IntReg2        res              1
;... declare shared variables

_UpperBank0    udata            060h     ;Banked file memory registers
RegA           res              1
;...declare application variables

_Bank1         udata            0100h    ;Banked file memory registers
N              res              1
;...declare application variables

;CODE
_ResetCPU       code        0
                movlw       b'01100000'  ;init MCPU file registers
                movwf       ;...
                goto        ContinueInitCpu

_Interrupt      code        8
                movlb       high _Bank1
;
;interrupt code
;
                retfie      ;return from interrupt
;
ContinueInitCpu
                movlw       b'01100000'   ;init MCPU file registers
                movwf       ;...
;...
;
; Application code 
;
```

**Than use MPLAB built in simulator to check code and report...**